# Close whichever jQuery Mobile dialog is open. jQuery Mobile / jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two jQuery Mobile dialogs containing forms. I want them to both call the same function when they close. Only one will be open at a time. So I need the function to tell which is open and to target that one.

The function closes the dialog and refreshes the page.

Right now I have it working but only for one dialog.

```
        function backToPage(){
            //jQuery('#save-contact-dialog').dialog('close');   
            $('#edit-contact-dialog').dialog('close');
            location.reload();
        };
```

So maybe

```
        function backToPage(){
            if($('#save-contact-dialog').dialog() == open{
                   $('#save-contact-dialog').dialog('close');
                   location.reload();
             }else  
                   $('#edit-contact-dialog').dialog('close');
                   location.reload();
        };
```

Obviously this is jibberish but if someone could help with a non-jibberish answer, I would be very happy!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$(".ui-dialog:visible").dialog("close");
```

It should close any visible dialogs.